# K8s - Traefik no available port after upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, traefik

Hi i had deployed Traefik over helm3 on microk8s with these values:

```
---
deployment:
  enabled: true

hostNetwork: true
service:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    web:  
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30183
      targetPort: 80
      redirectTo: websecure
    websecure:
      port: 443
      nodePort: null

ingressRoute:
  dashboard:
    enabled: false

additionalArguments:
  - --entryPoints.web.address=:8080/tcp
  - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp
  - --api=true
  - --api.insecure=true
  - --api.dashboard=true
  - --providers.kubernetesingress=true
  - --providers.kubernetescrd=true
  - --providers.kubernetesingress.ingressclass=traefik
  - --serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true
  - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/data/acme.json
  - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=email@example.com
  - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web

securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop: [ALL]
    add: [NET_BIND_SERVICE]
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  runAsGroup: 0
  runAsNonRoot: false
  runAsUser: 0
```

Then i upgraded traefik with added configMap in values.yml:

```
volumes:
  - mountPath: /etc/traefik
    name: traefik-config
    type: configMap
```

But traefik cant start because 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports. Uninstall and install again doesn't resolved problem.

------ EDIT

After adding new node, treafik have new error:
0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports, 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.

Comment: Could you please provide your logs?

Comment: Logs from traefik? They are empty because pod is in pending state

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: Since there is used `hostNetwork: true` port can literally be taken on one node. The second node had taint `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable`. See doc about [taint and toleration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#taint-based-evictions)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor No

Comment: Did you check the node that had taint?